# Next.js | How to improve seo when doing dynamic routing with ssr

Tags: reactjs, next.js, url-routing

I am writing dynamic routes code in, like the code below. So my question is, this dynamic routes page is not reflected in google at all. I have dynamically set the title of this page, but when I search for that title in google, it doesn't show up. What should I do?

src/pages/salon/[[...salon]].js （abridged edition）

```js
import React from 'react'
// Firebase
import { db } from "../../../firebaseConfig"
import { doc, getDoc, updateDoc, arrayUnion, arrayRemove } from "firebase/firestore"
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth"

const Salon = ({ id, tag, data }) => {
    return (
<>
        <NextSeo
                title={data.title}
                description={data.description}
                url={data.url}
                canonical={data.url}
                openGraph={{
                    url: data.url,
                    title: data.title,
                    description: data.description,
                    type: "article",
                    images: [
                    {
                        url: data.mainImages[1],
                        width: 800,
                        height: 600,
                        alt: "Image",
                    }],
                }}
            />
        <div>{data.salonName}【{data.salonNameKana}】</div>
</>
    )
}

export default Salon


export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const url = context.params.salon
    const salonRef = doc(db, "salons", url[0])
    const salonSnap = await getDoc(salonRef)
    const data = salonSnap.data()

    if (!data) {
        return {
            redirect: {
                destination: '/',
                permanent: false,
            },
        }
    }

    return {
        props: {
            id: url[0],
            tag: url[1] ? url[1] : '',
            data: data
        }
    };
}
```

src/pages/salon/[[...salon]].js （full edition）

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react"
import Link from 'next/link'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import Image from "next/image"
// firebase関連
import { db } from "../../firebaseConfig"
import {
    collection,
    orderBy,
    query,
    getDocs,
    limit,
    where
} from 'firebase/firestore'
// fontawesome
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faSearch, faMapMarkedAlt, faSubway } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons"
// Redux関連
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { NextSeo } from "next-seo"

const Index = ({newSalonList}) => {
    const router = useRouter()
    const area = useSelector((state) => state.searchKey.area)

    return (
        <div className="Top">
            <NextSeo />
            {/* 検索 */}
            <div className="search">
                <div className="reserveText">イメコンサロンを検索する</div>
                <div className="area">
                    <p>{area}</p>
                    <Link href="area">
                        <a><button>エリア変更</button></a>
                    </Link>
                </div>
                <div className="form">
                    <form action="/search" method="GET" className="search-box">
                        <input type="text" name="query" placeholder="サロン名・エリア・メニューなどから検索" />
                        <button type="submit" value="&#xf002; 検索"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch} /></button> 
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div className="common_relative_image mainImg">
                    <Image
                        src='/imecon-personal-color.jpeg' 
                        alt="mainTopImg" 
                        className="mainImg"
                        layout="fill"
                        objectFit="contain"
                        priority
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="searchWay">
                    <button className="searchWayItem" onClick={(e) =>{
                        e.preventDefault()
                        router.push({
                            pathname: "/area",
                            // 検索する地域をクリックした後の遷移先のURLを渡す
                            query: {to:'area-search'} 
                        })
                    }}>
                        <div className="areaImage common_relative_image">
                            <Image 
                                src='/JapanMap.svg' 
                                alt="japanMap" 
                                layout="fill"
                                objectFit="contain"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <p><span>エリア</span><br />から探す</p>
                    </button>
                    <Link href="station">
                        <a className="searchWayItem" style={{cursor: "default", background: "#D9D9D9"}} onClick={ (event) => event.preventDefault() }>
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSubway} />
                            <p><span>駅</span>から探す</p>
                            <small style={{color: "red"}}>coming soon</small>
                        </a>
                    </Link>
                    <Link href="location">
                        <a className="searchWayItem" style={{cursor: "default", background: "#D9D9D9"}} onClick={ (event) => event.preventDefault() }>
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMapMarkedAlt} />
                            <p><span>現在地</span><br />から探す</p>
                            <small style={{color: "red"}}>coming soon</small>
                        </a>
                    </Link>
                </div>
            </div>
            {/* ブックマークから探す */}
            <Link href="/bookmark">
                <a className="bookMark">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" fill="#FF0100" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M12 4.248c-3.148-5.402-12-3.825-12 2.944 0 4.661 5.571 9.427 12 15.808 6.43-6.381 12-11.147 12-15.808 0-6.792-8.875-8.306-12-2.944z"/></svg>
                    ブックマークから探す
                </a>
            </Link>
            {/* お知らせ */}
            <div className="information">
                <div className="common_title">｜ Information</div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <Link href="/tosalons">
                            <a>掲載をご希望のサロン様はこちら</a>
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            {/* 新着サロン */}
            <div className="newSalon">
                <div className="common_title">｜ 新着のサロン</div>
                <ul>
                    {newSalonList.map((data) => {
                        return (
                            // 新着順のサロンを表示：useEffectで格納したデータ
                            <li className="newSalonMain" key={data.salonId}> 
                                <Link href={'/salon/' + data.salonId}>
                                    <a className="newSalonMainList">
                                        <div className="newSalonMainListImage common_relative_image">
                                            <Image 
                                                src={data.mainImageUrl} 
                                                alt="salonMainImage" 
                                                layout="fill"
                                                objectFit="contain"
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="newSalonMainListInfo">
                                            <p className="salonName">{data.salonName}{data.salonNameKana}</p>
                                            <div className="salonTraffic">
                                                <div className="common_relative_image salonTrafficImg">
                                                    <Image 
                                                        src='/traffic.svg' 
                                                        alt="traffic" 
                                                        layout="fill"
                                                        objectFit="contain"
                                                    />
                                                </div>
                                                <span>{data.address}</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="newSalonMainListInfoMenu">
                                                <div className="newSalonMainListInfoMenuTitle">{data.title}</div>
                                                <div className="newSalonMainListInfoMenuPrice">￥{data.price}</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </Link>
                            </li>
                        )
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Index

export async function getServerSideProps() {
    // firestoreから新着順サロンのドキュメントを5つ取得
    const salons = query(collection(db, "salons"), where('publish', "==", true), orderBy('createAt', "desc"), limit(5))
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(salons)
    // 一旦useEffect内で配列を作り、格納する。後でこの配列をuseStateに格納
    let subSalonList = []
    // 取得した新着順サロンのドキュメントから情報を取得し、subSalonListに格納
    await querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        subSalonList = [...subSalonList, {
            salonId: doc.id,
            salonName: doc._document.data.value.mapValue.fields.salonName.stringValue,
            salonNameKana: doc._document.data.value.mapValue.fields.salonNameKana ? '【' + doc._document.data.value.mapValue.fields.salonNameKana.stringValue  + '】': '',
            address: doc._document.data.value.mapValue.fields.access ? doc._document.data.value.mapValue.fields.access.stringValue: '',
            mainImageUrl: doc._document.data.value.mapValue.fields.mainImages.mapValue.fields[1].stringValue,
        }]
    })
    // サブコレクションの情報は↑で一緒に取得できなかったので、↓で格納する。subSalonListをループして、salonIdを元に順番に情報を取得し、subSalonListに格納している。
    for (const value of subSalonList) {
        try {
            // salonIdを元にmenuサブコレクション下のドキュメントでtopがtrueのものを検索&取得
            const q = query(collection(db, "salons", value.salonId, "menu"))
            const querySnapshot2 = await getDocs(q)
            value.title = querySnapshot2.docs[0]._document.data.value.mapValue.fields.title.stringValue
            value.price = querySnapshot2.docs[0]._document.data.value.mapValue.fields.price.integerValue.toLocaleString()
            value.time = querySnapshot2.docs[0]._document.data.value.mapValue.fields.time.integerValue.toLocaleString()
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err)
            return 'err'
        }
    }

    return {
        props: {
            newSalonList: subSalonList,
        }
    }
}
```

site meta tag

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no"><link rel="icon" href="https://kanunu-beauty.com/favicon.ico">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://kanunu-beauty.com/favicon.ico">
<title>Kanunu（カヌヌ）｜パーソナルカラー・骨格診断・顔タイプ診断などのイメコンサロンが探せる日本最大級の検索サイト</title>
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@kanunu_official">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@kanunu_official">
<meta property="og:image:alt" content="Kanunu_Image">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="800">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="600">
<meta property="og:locale" content="ja_JP"><meta property="og:site_name" content="Kanunu（カヌヌ）"><link rel="icon" href="https://kanunu-beauty.com/favicon.ico"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://kanunu-beauty.com/favicon.ico" sizes="76x76"><meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://kanunu-beauty.com/kanunu.png">
<meta name="description" content="パーソナルカラー・骨格診断・顔タイプ診断などのイメコンサロンが探せる日本最大級の検索サイト。２４時間いつでもネット検索OK。イメージコンサルティングを検索するならKanunu">
<meta property="og:title" content="Kanunu（カヌヌ）｜パーソナルカラー・骨格診断・顔タイプ診断などのイメコンサロンが探せる日本最大級の検索サイト">
<meta property="og:description" content="パーソナルカラー・骨格診断・顔タイプ診断などのイメコンサロンが探せる日本最大級の検索サイト。２４時間いつでもネット検索OK。イメージコンサルティングを検索するならKanunu">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://kanunu-beauty.com/">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<link rel="canonical" href="https://kanunu-beauty.com/">
<link rel="preload" as="image" imagesrcset="/_next/image?url=%2Fimecon-personal-color.jpeg&amp;w=640&amp;q=75 640w, /_next/image?url=%2Fimecon-personal-color.jpeg&amp;w=750&amp;q=75 750w, /_next/image?url=%2Fimecon-personal-color.jpeg&amp;w=828&amp;q=75 828w, /_next/image?url=%2Fimecon-personal-color.jpeg&amp;w=1080&amp;q=75 1080w, /_next/image?url=%2Fimecon-personal-color.jpeg&amp;w=1200&amp;q=75 1200w, /_next/image?url=%2Fimecon-personal-color.jpeg&amp;w=1920&amp;q=75 1920w, /_next/image?url=%2Fimecon-personal-color.jpeg&amp;w=2048&amp;q=75 2048w, /_next/image?url=%2Fimecon-personal-color.jpeg&amp;w=3840&amp;q=75 3840w" imagesizes="100vw">
<meta name="next-head-count" content="24">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ff889e"><script src="https://apis.google.com/_/scs/abc-static/_/js/k=gapi.lb.ja.5EzdJRYYqVI.O/m=gapi_iframes/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/rs=AHpOoo_YkgRfk9NA-tU81xmKmFrifcc8Yg/cb=gapi.loaded_0?le=scs" async=""></script><script src="https://partner.googleadservices.com/gampad/cookie.js?domain=kanunu-beauty.com&amp;callback=_gfp_s_&amp;client=ca-pub-3226715501424001&amp;cookie=ID%3Da210217fc7bc19a0-226fbd731ed100ba%3AT%3D1648307385%3ART%3D1648307385%3AS%3DALNI_Mbl4zhbFc5KZH7kiBhF4bogpQHECQ"></script><script src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/managed/js/adsense/m202205050101/show_ads_impl_fy2019.js?bust=31067451" id="google_shimpl"></script><script async="" src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-3226715501424001" crossorigin="anonymous" data-checked-head="true"></script><link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/css/3af99d7a8bc648e8.css" as="style"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/_next/static/css/3af99d7a8bc648e8.css" data-n-g=""><noscript data-n-css=""></noscript><script defer="" nomodule="" src="/_next/static/chunks/polyfills-5cd94c89d3acac5f.js"></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/webpack-5752944655d749a0.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/main-958eae9894028eb3.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app-7066ec57ee9a283b.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/675-a0e7bc4ebaaecba0.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/index-b8f101c1b5c4520a.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/c6OFukToh53vEUvjEggAL/_buildManifest.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/c6OFukToh53vEUvjEggAL/_ssgManifest.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/c6OFukToh53vEUvjEggAL/_middlewareManifest.js" defer=""></script>
<meta http-equiv="origin-trial" content="AxujKG9INjsZ8/gUq8+dTruNvk7RjZQ1oFhhgQbcTJKDnZfbzSTE81wvC2Hzaf3TW4avA76LTZEMdiedF1vIbA4AAABueyJvcmlnaW4iOiJodHRwczovL2ltYXNkay5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbTo0NDMiLCJmZWF0dXJlIjoiVHJ1c3RUb2tlbnMiLCJleHBpcnkiOjE2NTI3NzQ0MDAsImlzVGhpcmRQYXJ0eSI6dHJ1ZX0=">
<meta http-equiv="origin-trial" content="Azuce85ORtSnWe1MZDTv68qpaW3iHyfL9YbLRy0cwcCZwVnePnOmkUJlG8HGikmOwhZU22dElCcfrfX2HhrBPAkAAAB7eyJvcmlnaW4iOiJodHRwczovL2RvdWJsZWNsaWNrLm5ldDo0NDMiLCJmZWF0dXJlIjoiVHJ1c3RUb2tlbnMiLCJleHBpcnkiOjE2NTI3NzQ0MDAsImlzU3ViZG9tYWluIjp0cnVlLCJpc1RoaXJkUGFydHkiOnRydWV9">
<meta http-equiv="origin-trial" content="A16nvcdeoOAqrJcmjLRpl1I6f3McDD8EfofAYTt/P/H4/AWwB99nxiPp6kA0fXoiZav908Z8etuL16laFPUdfQsAAACBeyJvcmlnaW4iOiJodHRwczovL2dvb2dsZXRhZ3NlcnZpY2VzLmNvbTo0NDMiLCJmZWF0dXJlIjoiVHJ1c3RUb2tlbnMiLCJleHBpcnkiOjE2NTI3NzQ0MDAsImlzU3ViZG9tYWluIjp0cnVlLCJpc1RoaXJkUGFydHkiOnRydWV9">
<meta http-equiv="origin-trial" content="AxBHdr0J44vFBQtZUqX9sjiqf5yWZ/OcHRcRMN3H9TH+t90V/j3ENW6C8+igBZFXMJ7G3Pr8Dd13632aLng42wgAAACBeyJvcmlnaW4iOiJodHRwczovL2dvb2dsZXN5bmRpY2F0aW9uLmNvbTo0NDMiLCJmZWF0dXJlIjoiVHJ1c3RUb2tlbnMiLCJleHBpcnkiOjE2NTI3NzQ0MDAsImlzU3ViZG9tYWluIjp0cnVlLCJpc1RoaXJkUGFydHkiOnRydWV9">
<meta http-equiv="origin-trial" content="A88BWHFjcawUfKU3lIejLoryXoyjooBXLgWmGh+hNcqMK44cugvsI5YZbNarYvi3roc1fYbHA1AVbhAtuHZflgEAAAB2eyJvcmlnaW4iOiJodHRwczovL2dvb2dsZS5jb206NDQzIiwiZmVhdHVyZSI6IlRydXN0VG9rZW5zIiwiZXhwaXJ5IjoxNjUyNzc0NDAwLCJpc1N1YmRvbWFpbiI6dHJ1ZSwiaXNUaGlyZFBhcnR5Ijp0cnVlfQ==">
<meta http-equiv="origin-trial" content="AzoawhTRDevLR66Y6MROu167EDncFPBvcKOaQispTo9ouEt5LvcBjnRFqiAByRT+2cDHG1Yj4dXwpLeIhc98/gIAAACFeyJvcmlnaW4iOiJodHRwczovL2RvdWJsZWNsaWNrLm5ldDo0NDMiLCJmZWF0dXJlIjoiUHJpdmFjeVNhbmRib3hBZHNBUElzIiwiZXhwaXJ5IjoxNjYxMjk5MTk5LCJpc1N1YmRvbWFpbiI6dHJ1ZSwiaXNUaGlyZFBhcnR5Ijp0cnVlfQ==">
<meta http-equiv="origin-trial" content="A6+nc62kbJgC46ypOwRsNW6RkDn2x7tgRh0wp7jb3DtFF7oEhu1hhm4rdZHZ6zXvnKZLlYcBlQUImC4d3kKihAcAAACLeyJvcmlnaW4iOiJodHRwczovL2dvb2dsZXN5bmRpY2F0aW9uLmNvbTo0NDMiLCJmZWF0dXJlIjoiUHJpdmFjeVNhbmRib3hBZHNBUElzIiwiZXhwaXJ5IjoxNjYxMjk5MTk5LCJpc1N1YmRvbWFpbiI6dHJ1ZSwiaXNUaGlyZFBhcnR5Ijp0cnVlfQ==">
<meta http-equiv="origin-trial" content="A/9La288e7MDEU2ifusFnMg1C2Ij6uoa/Z/ylwJIXSsWfK37oESIPbxbt4IU86OGqDEPnNVruUiMjfKo65H/CQwAAACLeyJvcmlnaW4iOiJodHRwczovL2dvb2dsZXRhZ3NlcnZpY2VzLmNvbTo0NDMiLCJmZWF0dXJlIjoiUHJpdmFjeVNhbmRib3hBZHNBUElzIiwiZXhwaXJ5IjoxNjYxMjk5MTk5LCJpc1N1YmRvbWFpbiI6dHJ1ZSwiaXNUaGlyZFBhcnR5Ijp0cnVlfQ=="><link as="script" rel="prefetch" href="/_next/static/chunks/pages/mypage-141f665c92390596.js"><link as="script" rel="prefetch" href="/_next/static/chunks/733-e7d84bed7ed356fa.js"><link as="script" rel="prefetch" href="/_next/static/chunks/pages/bookmark-61fff4ba51ad8155.js"><link as="script" rel="prefetch" href="/_next/static/chunks/866-c05af8e23c872e2c.js"><link as="script" rel="prefetch" href="/_next/static/chunks/pages/signin-ae60a19128cbc932.js"><link as="script" rel="prefetch" href="/_next/static/chunks/932-f01e4d1c2aeb2e91.js"><link as="script" rel="prefetch" href="/_next/static/chunks/pages/area-bf69ae687aa602d8.js"><link as="script" rel="prefetch" href="/_next/static/chunks/pages/tosalons-79196977b12f1828.js"><link as="script" rel="prefetch" href="/_next/static/chunks/pages/salon/%5B%5B...salon%5D%5D-15ea0d621d053ed1.js"><link rel="preload" href="https://adservice.google.co.jp/adsid/integrator.js?domain=kanunu-beauty.com" as="script"><script type="text/javascript" src="https://adservice.google.co.jp/adsid/integrator.js?domain=kanunu-beauty.com"></script><link rel="preload" href="https://adservice.google.com/adsid/integrator.js?domain=kanunu-beauty.com" as="script"><script type="text/javascript" src="https://adservice.google.com/adsid/integrator.js?domain=kanunu-beauty.com"></script><script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=__iframefcb771037" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" gapi_processed="true"></script><link as="script" rel="prefetch" href="/_next/static/chunks/pages/privacy-policy-244018d019bd23ac.js"><link as="script" rel="prefetch" href="/_next/static/chunks/pages/terms-of-service-6bb94404533a0249.js">
</head>
```

_app.js

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import Script from 'next/script'
import Head from 'next/head'
import * as gtag from '../lib/gtag.js'
import { GA_TRACKING_ID } from '../lib/gtag'
import { Provider } from "react-redux"
import redux from '../components/store/redux.js'
import '../../public/styles/Common.scss'
import '../../public/styles/Top.scss'
import '../../public/styles/index.scss'
import '../../public/styles/Header.scss'
import '../../public/styles/Footer.scss'
import '../../public/styles/ToSalons.scss'
import '../../public/styles/Terms.scss'
import '../../public/styles/Area.scss'
import '../../public/styles/Salon.scss'
import '../../public/styles/Search.scss'
import '../../public/styles/Bookmark.scss'
import '../../public/styles/SignUp.scss'
import '../../public/styles/SignUp.scss'
import '../../public/styles/Mypage.scss'
import '../../public/styles/SignUp.scss'
import '../../public/styles/SignUp.scss'
import "../../public/styles/Pagination.scss"
import Header from '../components/block/Header.js'
import Footer from '../components/block/Footer.js'
import { DefaultSeo } from 'next-seo'
import SEO from '../../next-seo.config'

import { config } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css'
config.autoAddCss = false

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
    const router = useRouter()
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const handleComplete = (url) => {
            // google analyticsの設定
            gtag.pageview(url)
        };
        router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", handleComplete);
        router.events.on("routeChangeError", handleComplete);
        return () => {
            router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', handleComplete)
        }
    },[router])

    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" />
                <link rel="icon" href="https://test.com/favicon.ico" />
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://test.com/favicon.ico" />
            </Head>
            <DefaultSeo  {...SEO} />
            {/* Analytics */}
            <Script
                async
                src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${GA_TRACKING_ID}`}
            />
            <Script
                id="analytics"
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                    __html: `
                    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
                    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
                    gtag('js', new Date());
                    gtag('config', '${GA_TRACKING_ID}', {
                    page_path: window.location.pathname,
                    });
                `,
                }}
            />
            <Provider store={redux}>
                <Header />
                <Component {...pageProps} />
                <Footer />
            </Provider>
        </>
    )
}
```

_document.js

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';

class MyDocument extends Document {
    static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
        const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
        return { ...initialProps };
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <Html lang="ja">
            <Head>
                <meta charSet="UTF-8" />
                <meta name="theme-color" content="#ff889e" />
                {/* google広告 */}
                <script async 
                    src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=xxxxxxxxxxx"
                    crossOrigin="anonymous"></script>
            </Head>
            <body>
                <Main />
                <NextScript />
            </body>
        </Html>
        );
    }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

Comment: you import {  NextSeo } from 'next-seo' ?

Comment: Do you see the metatags in the HTML returned by the server if you check View Page Source? Do you have a custom `_app` file? If so, can you also share the code for it.

Comment: Check that the page actually has the right metatags. If it does, you probably just need to wait. It can take over a week for google to start showing results of your site in my experience.

Comment: hello H9ee! yes, I import nextseo from 'next-seo'. I added full version of salon.js.

Comment: hello juliomalves! Thank you for your comment. I edited and add site meta tags. Please check it.

Comment: hello FINDarkside! I know that too.This site was created over a month ago. I believe there is something wrong with it that it is not showing up in searches now.

Comment: If you paste the URL of that page into your browser, does the correct content show up?

Comment: Have you turned on server side rendering (SSR)?

Comment: Assuming that's the metatags you see when inspecting the Page Source, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the Next.js app/code. The issue lies elsewhere.

Comment: hello Stephen Ostermiller! yes,  the correct content show up.
What does it mean to turn on ssr in Next.js?

Comment: Hi!  juliomalves! I added _app.js and _document.js.Is there a problem with this files?

Comment: See https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages which describes pre-rendering and server side rendering in next.js

Comment: As an aside, I didn't get notified when you addressed me by name. I just happened to stumble back to this question because I saw that it had been edited.  To address somebody in comments and notify them use an `@` sign and start typing their name then rely on the auto-completion.  If the comment contains `@StephenOstermiller` I would get notified.

Comment: ping @juliomalves

Comment: ping @FINDarkside

Comment: @Maru I don't see anything in either `_document` or `_app` that would affect the metatags.